# UWP ScrollViewer unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, scrollviewer

When developing an app for the **UWP** platform I came across a case of unexpected behavior. When I had too much content to present on one page I took advantage of the **ScrollViewer** control, which should fix this problem.

The control allows the scrolling of the content, but the way it handles input is unnatural. When the control gets **Clicked**, so that no focusable control within the **ScrollViewer** is clicked, the **Focus** is passed to the first focusable control in it's content. This effectively means that the **ScrollViewer** scrolls back to the top, which is not the behavior that I would not expect.

I'd like the **ScrollViewer** retain it's current position, just as a webpage does. A webpage does not scroll back to the first focusable control if one were to click on an empty place. Another similar example is that a **Grid** or **Stackpanel** does not pass the focus to one of it's children when clicked.

Below is some xaml code that demonstrates said behavior, just create a new **UWP project** and place this inside the grid of the generated **MainPage.xaml**:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="400"> <!-- Unexpected and unnatrual behavior -->
    <StackPanel Width="250" Background="DarkGray" Padding="10"> <!-- With Content Height > ScrollViewer Height -->
        <TextBlock Text="Unnatural scroll behavior" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox Text="Some focusable control"/>
        <TextBlock Height="800" Text="On focus => pass focus to first available => scroll to the top" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBox Text="Some focusable control"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I did come up with a solution, however it seems quite weird that this would be the correct way to solve the current problem:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="400">
    <!-- Corrected behaviour, but extra ContentControl. Easily forgotten -->
    <ContentControl>
        <StackPanel Width="250" Background="Gray" Padding="10">
            <!-- With Content Height > ScrollViewer Height -->
            <TextBlock Text="Corrected scroll behavior" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox Text="Some focusable control"/>
            <TextBlock Height="800" Text="On focus => no scroll" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBox Text="Some focusable control"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works, however it's quite annoying to always remember to add the **ContentControl**, which is why I will post an answer that implements my solution in a better way.

The question remains: Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution implemented in a more developer friendly way by creating a custom **UserControl** that handles the **ContentControl**.

Scroller.xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Controls.Scroller"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <ScrollViewer Name="ScrollerControl" Height="{x:Bind Height, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="{x:Bind Width, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind ScrollContent}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

Scroller.xaml.cs:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;

namespace Controls
{
    [ContentProperty(Name = "ScrollContent")]
    public sealed partial class Scroller : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollContent", typeof(object), typeof(object), new PropertyMetadata(new Grid()));

        public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer { get { return ScrollerControl; } }
        public object ScrollContent { get { return GetValue(ScrollContentProperty); } set { SetValue(ScrollContentProperty, value); } }

        public Scroller()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

First add the following line to a Page's xaml:

```
xmlns:cont="using:Controls"
```

Then use the control in the following way:

```
<cont:Scroller Height="400" x:Name="ScrollControl">
    <!-- Place any content in here -->
    <!-- The content below is just for example -->
    <StackPanel Width="250" Background="DarkGray" Padding="10">
        <TextBlock Text="Corrected scroll behaviour" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox Text="Some focusable control"/>
        <TextBlock Height="800" Text="On focus => no scroll" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBox Text="Some focusable control"/>
    </StackPanel>
</cont:Scroller>
```

Note that x:Name must be used to refer to the control in code. Also if you want to access the **ScrollViewer**, then use

```
ScrollControl.ScrollViewer
```

Comment: @CoCaIceDew I left it unchecked first as I wanted to wait about a week and see if someone had any better solutions to the problem presented. However I did forget to accept my solution, so thanks for reminding!